# Push Foreach Inside Foreach Into Same Keys Object With PHP

Tags: php

How to save foreach result from above foreach it self into the same keys object? i have code php like this below:

**Php code**

```
$get_age_autism = $this->getdata->getAutismAge();
$get_age_normal = $this->getdata->getNormalAge();
$row_autism = 243;
$row_normal = 49;

$data = [];
foreach ($get_age_autism as $a_autism) {
   foreach ($get_age_normal as $a_normal) {
        $rowAge['AGE_AUTISM'] = number_format($a_autism['age_autism'] / $row_autism, 6);
        $rowAge['AGE_NORMAL'] =  number_format($a_normal['age_normal'] / $row_normal, 6);
   }
   $data[$a_autism['age']] =  $rowAge;
 }
```

`$row_autism` and `$row_format` its only variable contain a number, input only  `$get_age_autism` and `$get_age_normal` come from the model below

**The Model**:

```
function getAutismAge()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT age, COUNT(age) age_autism
    FROM data_latih
    WHERE age NOT IN (0)
    AND autism = 'yes'
    GROUP BY age");
    return $query->result_array();
}
function getNormalAge()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT age, COUNT(age) age_normal
    FROM data_latih
    WHERE age NOT IN (0)
    AND autism = 'no'
    GROUP BY age");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

My expectation is the red square would appear all of data from the result of `foreach($get_age_normal as $a_normal)`, but the result only looped data from the last result of `$get_age_normal`, what i have missed?

Comment: `$row_autism` ? Whats that? `$row_normal` Whats that??

Comment: Please provide a proper sample of your input. We can't determine what went wrong based solely on the output.

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated

Comment: @El_Vanja Updated

Answer (score 0):

You collecting data inside `$rowAge['AGE_AUTISM']` not inside `$rowAge['AGE_AUTISM'][]`, so the other data is lost, because of `$rowAge['AGE_AUTISM']` is not array that can collect all data, is is simple `key => value`, but you need `key => [value, value value]`.

Try this:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($get_age_autism as $a_autism) {
   foreach ($get_age_normal as $a_normal) {
        $rowAge['AGE_AUTISM'][] = number_format($a_autism['age_autism'] / $row_autism, 6);
        $rowAge['AGE_NORMAL'][] =  number_format($a_normal['age_normal'] / $row_normal, 6);
   }
   $data[$a_autism['age']] =  $rowAge;
 }
```